# Access custom ListView object from outside

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have ListView with items containing a Button among others. I start an Asynctask from the Adapter class of the ListView:

```
holder.btn_follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {           
        new Follow_Async().execute(arr_id.get(position), arr_name.get(position));
    }

   }
});
```

This is my Asynctask:

```
public class Follow_Async extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

//here
            Toast.makeText(Activity_Followers2.this, "You are now following " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() { 

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                params_follow = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params_follow.add(new BasicNameValuePair("session_userid", session_userid));
                params_follow.add(new BasicNameValuePair("friend_userid", params[0]));
                JSONParser jsonParser; jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(add_follow, "POST", params_follow);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return params[1];
        }

    }
```

In the PostExecute() I want to change the text of the Button I have just clicked to Unfollow. How can I access it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass your button as a parameter to the AsyncTask constructor:

**In the adapter:**

```
final thisButton = holder.btn_follow; // <------------ add a final Button field

thisButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {           
        new Follow_Async(thisButton).   //<------------- pass button to AsyncTask
             execute(arr_id.get(position), arr_name.get(position));
    }
   }
});
```

**And in the AsyncTask:**

```
class Follow_Async extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private final Button button;

    public Follow_Async(Button button) {  //<------------- pass button to constructor
        this.button = button;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        this.button.setText(""); //<--------------- do something with button
    }

}
```